# How to use list comprehension in list derived class

Tags: python, constructor, list-comprehension, derived-class

I have a list derived class and want to assign its contents using list comprehension
This is the sample code:

```
class MyList(list):
    def __init__(self, some_data):
        self = [Foo(x) for x in some_data]

    def customFilter(self):
        self = [x for x in self if x.Selected]
```

Of course this does not work because the assignment to self just creates a local variable.
Is there a pythonic way to achieve this without using for loop?

Comment: Why do you need to derive from `list`?

Comment: Main reason is for adding some additional methods i.e. extending the list fuctionality

Comment: Surely the purpose of deriving is to be reused?

Comment: I added the custom method to the code to illustrate why I derived from list

Comment: @JuliusG Are you redefining self? I'm confused.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's probably better to use [Collections.UserList](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.UserList), which is made for subclassing. It gives you a `data` property which holds the lists contents and avoids the problem of assigning to `self`:

```
from collections import UserList

def Foo(c):
    return c * 2

class MyList(UserList):
    def __init__(self, some_data):
        self.data = [Foo(x) for x in some_data]

MyList([1, 2, 3])
# [2, 4, 6]
```

Comment: `self.extend(Foo(x) for x in some_data)` would perform slightly better as you would not create an intermediary list

Answer (score 2):

Why not call `list`'s initialiser?

```
list.__init__(self, (Foo(x) for x in some_data))
```

Or even, why do you need another class?

```
def create_foos(some_data):
    return [Foo(x) for x in some_data]
```

or

```
list(map(Foo, some_data))
```